# Open Explorer to current working directory and file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to open explorer via powershell to the current working direcoty and file within in the current working directory.

My main goal is to open an explorer window via powershell to the specified search term, but it keeps asking me to find an app that works with this.

```
explorer search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20C:\MyLOcation&crumb=System.Generic.String%3AFLO**&crumb=location:%5C%5CC:\MyLocation
```

This works in Run and CMD, but not powershell.

So I created a internet shortcut on my computer and I am trying to launch that from powershell and it can't find it unless I hardcode the path. I would rather find the path programmatically.

```
$cwd = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName + "\MyLocation.url"
explorer $($cwd)
```

Should launch the path to `C:\MyLocation`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ii .
```

to open the current directory via PowerShell

Comment: Thanks, but how would I concatenate the file in this folder to this command and open in explorer?

Comment: You can replace the dot with any path to your folder, `ii c:\path\to\folder`

Comment: Not really what I am looking for, that requires me to hardcode which I am trying to avoid.